# HpUX: correct vgreduce

Tags: lvm, hp-ux

I want to remove a disk from root mirror.
The disk to remove is `/dev/disk/disk2_p2`

```
lvreduce -m 0 /dev/vg00/lvol1 /dev/disk/disk2_p2
lvreduce -m 0 /dev/vg00/lvol2 /dev/disk/disk2_p2
lvreduce -m 0 /dev/vg00/lvol3 /dev/disk/disk2_p2
lvreduce -m 0 /dev/vg00/lvol4 /dev/disk/disk2_p2
lvreduce -m 0 /dev/vg00/lvol5 /dev/disk/disk2_p2
lvreduce -m 0 /dev/vg00/lvol6 /dev/disk/disk2_p2
lvreduce -m 0 /dev/vg00/lvol7 /dev/disk/disk2_p2
```

OK.
But when I want to remove the disk

```
vgreduce vg00 /dev/disk/disk2_p2
```

it said

```
vgreduce: Physical volume "/dev/disk/disk2_p2" could not be removed since some of its
physical extents are still in use.
```

I tried to check

```
for i in /dev/vg00/lvol*;do lvdisplay -v $i|wc -l;done
```

And the output is always the same.
How to reduce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move the extents to another disk, e.g., with `pvmove`.  This is clarified in *[4.3.7. Removing Physical Volumes from a Volume Group](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/VG_remove_PV.html)* (notwithstanding the different operating system, the advice mostly applies without change).

Further reading:

- [pvmove(1M)](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man1m/pvmove.1m.html) (HPUX)
- [hp ux problem with vgreduce](http://community.hpe.com/t5/System-Administration/hp-ux-problem-with-vgreduce/td-p/4532481)